# Функция работает не так как нужно!

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Мой код:**

```
String.prototype.translate = function(vars){
  for (const [KEY, value] of Object.entries(vars)) {
      return this.replace(/\%(KEY)\%/g,value)
  }
}
```

**Должно быть так:**

```
Congratulations,niksonbinsk on leveling up: 6
```

**А на самом деле получается вот так:**

```
Congratulations,%name% on leveling up: %level%
```

**Что я делаю не так?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
String.prototype.translate = function(vars){
  var str = this;
  for (const [KEY, value] of Object.entries(vars)) {
    console.log(KEY, value);
    str = str.replace(new RegExp(`%${KEY}%`, 'g'), value)
  }
  return str;
}

console.log("Congratulations,%name% on leveling up: %level%".translate({
  name: "niksonbinsk",
  level: 6
}));
```

Comment: Вам тоже огромное спасибо

Answer (score 2):

1. Для использования значения переменной в регулярном выражении нужно воспользоваться конструктором [`new RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp)
2. [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) сразу прекращает выполнение цикла и метода, поэтому сейчас в цикле выполняется только первая итерация.
3. метод [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) не меняет исходную строку, поэтому нужно сохранять результат на каждой итерации

В итоге код может выглядеть так:

```
String.prototype.translate = function(vars){
  var result = this;
  for (const [KEY, value] of Object.entries(vars)) {
      result = result.replace(new RegExp('\\%(' + KEY + ')\\%', 'g'),value)
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо,ещё раз :)